# Creating my own string functions

Tags: python

```
def tlower(str1):
    list = list(str1)
    final = ''
    for char in range(0,len(str1)):
        if list[char] in UPPERCASE:
            for ascii in range(0,len(UPPERCASE)):
                if list[char] == UPPERCASE[ascii]:
                    list[char] = LOWERCASE[ascii]
        final += list[char]
    return final
```

NOTE - UPPERCASE and LOWERCASE are strings of all upper/lowercase letters

NOTE - can NOT use any string functions built into python (Replace, etc..)

I have this function to turn any string into all lower case, (Yes i know there is a built in function..) But compared to my other string functions I have created, this is fairly long, any better approach I should take to do doing this?

Comment: Don't call a list `list`. **Especially** if you're actually using the `list()` builtin. You also don't want to iterate over range(len(something)); use enumerate.

Comment: rather than searching the list of uppercase letters, you could try, `list[char] += LOWERCASE[UPPERCASE.index(list[char])]`  I haven't tested this, which is why it's a comment.  Would eliminate your inner-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def to_lower(s, trans=dict(zip(UPPERCASE, LOWERCASE))):
    return ''.join(trans.get(ch,ch) for ch in s)

print to_lower('This Is a TEST')   # => 'this is a test'
```

Edit:

`zip()` takes two lists and returns pairs of values, ie

```
zip('ABC', 'abc')    # => [('A','a'), ('B','b'), ('C','c')]
```

`dict()` makes a dictionary - in this case,

```
{'A':'a', 'B':'b', 'C':'c'}
```

`trans.get(x, y)` is a more compact way of saying as `trans[x] if x in trans else y`. In this case, "if you have a lowercase version of this letter, return it, otherwise give back the original letter".

and if you don't like .join, how about reduce?

```
from operator import add

def to_lower(s, trans=dict(zip(UPPERCASE, LOWERCASE))):
    return reduce(add, (trans.get(ch,ch) for ch in s), '')
```

Comment: can't use .join, it is a string function, also, mind explaining what this does exactly?

Comment: Wow. That is pretty much exactly what I wrote.

Comment: @Brian: you can loop over [trans.get(ch,ch) for ch in s] and add each to a string for the same effect, although this is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Re: `return [trans.get(ch,ch) for ch in s]` But this returns an array. Write an implementation of `join`.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!  This seems a lot better, I really appreciate the help and explanation to help me actually understand it then to just copy.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness:

```
def to_lower(string):
    ords = (ord(c) for c in string)
    return ''.join(chr(o + 32 * (65 <= o <= 90)) for o in ords)
```

Comment: Won't work with codecs not compatible with ASCII, but +1 for those numbers. :)